# Getting: go: error loading module requirements

Tags: go, go-modules

I am trying to run a go script for SLACK bot that downloaded from git.
https://github.com/nlopes/slack/blob/master/examples/websocket/websocket.go#L34

I replaced the auth code of my bot in the websocket.go

```
rchughta@C02WW32YHTD6 ~/g/s/e/websocket> go run websocket.go
go: finding github.com/pmezard/go-difflib v1.0.0
go: finding github.com/davecgh/go-spew v1.1.1
go: finding github.com/stretchr/testify v1.2.2
go: finding github.com/pkg/errors v0.8.0
go: finding github.com/gorilla/websocket v1.2.0
go: github.com/gorilla/websocket@v1.2.0: unknown revision v1.2.0
go: github.com/davecgh/go-spew@v1.1.1: unknown revision v1.1.1
go: github.com/pkg/errors@v0.8.0: unknown revision v0.8.0
go: github.com/stretchr/testify@v1.2.2: unknown revision v1.2.2
go: github.com/pmezard/go-difflib@v1.0.0: unknown revision v1.0.0
go: error loading module requirements
```

Comment: There are no *modules* with the required versions. The git tags exist, but point to versions before the introduction of the respective go.mod files. Run `go get -u -t ./...` to update the dependencies to their latest versions, or re-create the module (you probably want a different name anyway).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you are using the latest Go 1.13.1.

If `go mod tidy` does not solve the issue, check that a simple `go get github.com/gorilla/websocket@v1.2.0` works.

If it does not, it could be, [as in this thread](https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/trouble-with-go-module-version-in-docker-build/14239/2), a proxy configuration issue: it depends on your local environment, you might need to set a company proxy server to get anything.

---

Update August 2020: note that [with Go 1.15](https://golang.org/doc/go1.15#go-command):

> The `GOPROXY` environment variable now supports skipping proxies that return errors.
>
> Proxy URLs may now be separated with either commas (`,`) or pipe characters (`|`).
>
> - If a proxy URL is followed by a comma, the `go` command will only try the next proxy in the list after a 404 or 410 HTTP response.
> - If a proxy URL is followed by a pipe character, the `go` command will try the next proxy in the list after any error.
>
> Note that the default value of GOPROXY remains `https://proxy.golang.org,direct`, which does not fall back to direct in case of errors.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an issue with the GOPROXY set. What's the output of `go env`?